# How do World Events work in Pocket Planes?

Tags: ios, pocket-planes

When I am part of a World Event, how are the prizes distributed. When it says top 10 gets "X" does everyone in the top 10 group of flight crews get it or the top ten of every separate flight crew that reached the quota for flights. Also another question is whether the quota for flights is just your flights or the total flights of everyone in the crew.

Answer (score 3):

The ranking applies to the whole group, meaning every *contributing* member in the top X group gets the prize.

A *contributing* member is someone who worked towards the goal, usually a handful of contributing actions are enough to be eligible to the prize. The quota is cumulative between the whole group, meaning not all members need to participate for a group to reach the top, but only participating members will be eligible for the final prize.

Comment: The number of items required in order to win the award is located under "flight crew --> prizes". Generally it is 50 jobs, so it says "Deliver 50 jobs to qualify for prizes." You also have to be in a flight crew in order to win prizes. I highly recommend TOUCHARCADE. It nearly always comes in first place.